# Probabilistic Considerations on the Calculation of Shannon's Entropy in a Network Traffic

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, statistics, entropy

I have a network dump in PCAP format (dump.pcap) and I am trying to compute the entropy of the Source and Destination IPs.

I am using the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

sample_ips = [
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.000",
]

C = collections.Counter(sample_ips)
counts = np.array(list(C.values()),dtype=float)
#counts  = np.array(C.values(),dtype=float)
prob    = counts/counts.sum()
shannon_entropy = (-prob*np.log2(prob)).sum()
print (shannon_entropy)
```

I have two network traffic from lab experiment: one free of attacks (semAtaque.pcap) and another with DDoS attacks (Attacks.pcap).

The IP of the server that suffered the attack: 192.168.1.5

When calculating this way, some doubts arise:

1.I am considering a discrete probability distribution and equally likely outcomes. Is that correct? Is that reasonable?

2.How to validate the experiment? I am thinking of a hypothesis test with the following null hypothesis:
"The entropy value allows you to detect the attack" 
Is that ok?

What would be a good hypothesis test for the case (the sample space is about 40)?

Comment: You might get additional responses in the Network Engineering exchange. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah stackoverflow is more for bug fixes then statistics and entropy

Comment: @lit: Thanks! Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I think Shannons entropy measures a sort of balancedness of the different IP-s in your sample.  If one IP dominates, you get low entropy.  I am afraid you cannot do a general test here--it depends on your network.  You may consider just looking at the entropy for attack-free server over long period of time, and constructing empirical distribution based on what you see.  Now you can build your custom test if a particular pattern is normal or not.

Comment: @Ott Toomet : thanks! What do you think about "hypothesis test"?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question...  You have H0: everything is normal vs H1: the entropy deviates too much from the normal...  Feel free to explain if I am completely off...

Comment: @Ott Toomet:H0 -> de values of entropy allow to detect a DDoS attack!

Comment: May or may not, it depends on how much does the entropy actually differ between DDoS and normal mode.  (This is called power of the test.)

Comment: @Ott Toomet :The entropy is always bigger during an attack!!! Csould you suggest a test?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do a well-known test, such as chi2-test.  (You may be able to, but then you have to make some assumptions about how entropy normally looks like.)  But you simply observe the frequency of all normal days (say, of 1000 days), and when entropy differs from what you have normally seen, you rise a red flag.  This is, essentially, how statistical tests work, just usually you are computing theoretical bounds for what to consider non-normal.